# Search for the same term in mutliple dataframes

Tags: r, search, loops, dataframe

I have a list of data.frames [or more accurately, [laf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LaF/index.html) objects that point to them].
The idea is to search for the same term in all data frames and extract the rows.

```
search.list=c("f.201301","f.201302","f.201303") # data frames list
column='Actor1Code'
item='MNC'

# this works:
test1=f.201301[f.201301[,column]==item]
test2=f.201302[f.201302[,column]==item]
test3=f.201303[f.201303[,column]==item]
test=rbind(test1,test2,test3)

# but this doesn't:

for (i in 1:length(search.list)) {
  search.list[i][search.list[i][,column]==item]
}

Error in search.list[i][, column] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Maybe as short explanation in addition to @Ferdinands answer: `search.list[i]` is an object of type `character` and not the `data.frame` you are looking for. Accordingly, calling `"["` on this `character` must fail. `get(search.list[i])` searches the current environment for an object with the variable name `search.list[i]` and returns ist. As additional hint: You should use `seq_along(search.list)` instead of `1:length(search.list)` since this is rather fail-safe. Or you use `for( search.item in search.list ){ x <- get(search.item); ...}` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
result <- list()

for (i in 1:length(search.list))
{
  x <- get(search.list[i])
  result[[i]] <- x[x[,column]==item]
}

do.call(rbind, result)
```